Discrepancy when using Opportunity Splits for Forecasting Expected Revenue
Requirement: We want to do Sales Forecasting based on the Expected Revenue field on Opportunity (i.e. Probability x Amount).
Based on this StackExchange post, it looks like we have to enable Opportunity Teams and add a custom "Split Type". I did that, however when I try to add a new Forecast Type, I cannot choose the "Expected Revenue" field on the Opportunity object. It just doesn't appear as an option. The only way I can create a Forecast on Expected Revenue is by building the Forecast on the "Opportunity Split" object and selecting the new custom split type I created. I did this too. See gif below to show what I mean.

Although I don't understand WHY I need to create a split and why I can only create a Forecast on the split, it does seem to work. Mostly... However today a colleague just pointed out a weird discrepancy in the Forecast where one particular Opportunity is getting a Forecast Amount of $0 (see screenshot below). I've checked the Opportunity record high and low and can't really see any issues with it - all the relevant fields are populated.

I even added the "Opportunity Split" component onto the lightning record page and had a look at it on this particular Opportunity to see if I could see anything wrong. I've never used Splits before so I don't know much about it, but it looks mostly correct to me - it is reflecting a "Split" amount of $10k which matches the expected revenue.

Does anyone have any insights into:

Why this discrepancy might be occurring?
Why I can't created a normal Forecast on the Opportunity object and why I HAVE to forecast on an Opportunity Split??

Thanks in advance!

Salesforce Support were helpful in figuring this one out. The main takeaway/learning for me here is that it is more useful to use the related lists for Splits and Team Members for troubleshooting than the "Opportunity Split" lightning component.
The related lists, unlike the component, showed that there was:
a) a 2nd Team Member added to the Opportunity Team for this record (no idea why/how), and
b) the split for this Team Member was set to 0%.
Something funny must have happened during the data migration for this record which caused a 2nd Team Member and a 0% Split for them to be added, which was the reason for the discrepancy. Once I corrected this data, the Forecasted Amount reflected correctly.
